# Ansible decprecation warning Instead of using `result|search` use `result is search`, but how?

Tags: ansible, telnet, deprecation-warning

I have a simple playbook:

```
---
- name: cat resolv.conf
  telnet:
      user: "{{ foxuser }}"
      password: "{{ foxpass }}"
      login_prompt: "login:"
      prompts: "#"
      command:
          - grep 192.168.178.6  /etc/resolv.conf

  register: resolv
  changed_when: not( resolv.output | join('') | search('nameserver'))
  notify: update resolv.conf
```

This works, but it throws a deprecation warning;

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using tests as filters is deprecated. Instead of using `result|search` use `result is search`. This feature will be removed in version 2.9.
```

I tried:

```
changed_when: not('nameserver' in resolv.output )
```

but that always seems to be true, even when `nameserver` is in `resolv.output`. Somehow, the `join` seems an essential part of the expression.

Note that `resolv` contains:

```
"resolv": {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": false, 
    "output": [
        " grep 192.168.178.6  /etc/resolv.conf\r\nnameserver 192.168.178.6\r\n[root@foxboard /root]1068#"
    ]
}
```

I cannot seem to find a working solution without the filter. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work (simulated test does for me):

---

```
- name: cat resolv.conf
  telnet:
      user: "{{ foxuser }}"
      password: "{{ foxpass }}"
      login_prompt: "login:"
      prompts: "#"
      command:
          - grep 192.168.178.6  /etc/resolv.conf

  register: resolv
  changed_when: not ( resolv.output | join('') ) is search('nameserver')
  notify: update resolv.conf
```

Using the search function as part of a filter appears to be what triggers the deprecation warning.